# lambda function c++ capture by value reset its values, why?

Tags: c++, lambda

Can someone explain me why localVar after being incremented by 1 is reset back to 10? Looks like the lambdas make copies of the capture-by-value on the stack before executing them.

```
void lambdaTest()
{
    int localVar = 10;

    // Access all local variables by reference
    auto byRef = [&] ()
    {
        cout << "localVar = " << ++localVar << endl;
    };

    // Access all local variables by value
    auto byValue = [=] () mutable 
    {
        cout << "localVar = " << localVar << endl;
    };


    byRef();        // localVar = 11
    byValue();      // localVar = 10, why?
}
```

Comment: The values are captured when the lambda is defined, not when it's used.

Comment: Say you returned the by-value lambda instead of calling it. `localVar` wouldn't even exist, so capturing at the point of use is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what they do.

Lambdas, internally, are structs with an `operator()` set up for you.  When you ask a lambda to capture-by-value, the struct stores a *copy* of any local variables that are referenced as members of the struct.  Thus, what you're seeing isn't `localVar` being reset, you're seeing *the lambda's copy of* `localVar`.

Here's an example that illustrates this behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    int localVar = 10;
    auto byRef = [&]() {
        std::cout << "byRef = " << ++localVar << '\n';
    };
    auto byValue = [=]() mutable {
        // `mutable` lets us make changes to the *copy* of `localVar`
        std::cout << "byVal = " << localVar++ << '\n';
    };
    byRef();   // byRef = 11  -> actual localVar is now 11
    byRef();   // byRef = 12  -> actual localVar is now 12
    byRef();   // byRef = 13  -> actual localVar is now 13
    byValue(); // byVal = 10  -> copied localVar is now 11
    byValue(); // byVal = 11  -> copied localVar is now 12
    assert(localVar == 13);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a0cc5083e9b9d81)

Answer (score 0):

just add another output.

```
void lambdaTest()
{
    int localVar = 10;

    // Access all local variables by reference
    auto byRef = [&] ()
    {
        cout << "localVar = " << ++localVar << endl;
    };

    // Access all local variables by value
    auto byValue = [=] () mutable
    {
        cout << "localVar = " << localVar << endl;
    };


    byRef();        // localVar = 11
    byValue();      // localVar = 10
    cout <<localVar << endl; // localVar = 11
}
```

c++ 11 capture-by-value capture values when lambda is defined.so, lambda haven't change value outside.